# How to setup oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow in azure AD application from console?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-cli

Is there any way to change property oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow in azure AD application via Azure CLI or Azure PowerShell?

Answer (score 3):

If you just need the IdToken checked, you might want to use the property **-Oauth2RequirePostResponse**

Update cmd:

```bsh
Connect-AzureAD
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId {yourAppId} -Oauth2RequirePostResponse $true
```

Create cmd:

```bsh
New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "MyApp" `
                       -HomePage "https:www.myapp.com" `
                       -LogoutUrl "https:www.myapp.com/signout-oidc" `
                       -ReplyUrls  "https:www.myapp.com/signin-oidc" `
                       -IdentifierUris "https://tenant.onmicrosoft.com/MyApp" `
                       -Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow $false `
                       -Oauth2RequirePostResponse $true
```

Answer (score 2):

The built-in Powershell or CLI does not support to set the `oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow` currently. Also, it seems the property just could be found in the manifest of the AD App, I could not find it in any doc(including the MS Graph or Azure AD Graph).

But per my test, you could set the `oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow` via Azure AD Graph API.

There are two ways for you to call the Azure AD Graph API, use Azure AD Graph Explorer or Powershell.

- **Use Azure AD Graph Explorer**

Use [Azure AD Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/#), just login your user account(make sure you have the permission to update the application), then call the API as below.

```
PATCH https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/applications/{object id of the application}?api-version=1.6

{
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow":true
}
```

**Note**: When you send the request, it seems the progress bar will never finish, I am not sure if it is a bug, but actually it works after a while, you just need to change the `PATCH` to `GET` to check the `oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow` of the application.

[image]

- **Use PowerShell**

If you want to use PowerShell, follow the steps below.

1.[Create an Azure Active Directory application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application), then [Create a new application secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-a-new-application-secret) and [Get values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-values-for-signing-in).

2.Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `App registrations` -> find and click your app -> `API permissions` -> `Add a permission` -> select `Azure Active Directory Graph` -> click `Application permissions` -> select the `Application.ReadWrite.All` permission -> click `Add permissions` -> click **`Grant admin consent for xxx`**.

[image]

3.Then use the powershell script below, it works fine on my side(it will return nothing when succeed), you can check the result in the portal or use Azure AD Graph Explorer.

```
$ClientID       = "a6ec906d-xxxxx00dd3" #ApplicationID
$ClientSecret   = "XwaNxxxxx/44"  #key from Application
$tennantid      = "bb58xxxxxxd6c65"
$objectid       = "ca8xxxef66db07c0" #object id of the application

$TokenEndpoint = {https://login.windows.net/{0}/oauth2/token} -f $tennantid 
$ARMResource = "https://graph.windows.net/";

$Body = @{
        'resource'= $ARMResource
        'client_id' = $ClientID
        'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'
        'client_secret' = $ClientSecret
}

$params = @{
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    Headers = @{'accept'='application/json'}
    Body = $Body
    Method = 'Post'
    URI = $TokenEndpoint
}

$token = Invoke-RestMethod @params

$accesstoken = $token.access_token

$url = {https://graph.windows.net/{0}/applications/{1}?api-version=1.6} -f $tennantid,$objectid

$header = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $accesstoken
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}

$json = @{
    oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow = 'false' #or true
}

$body = $json | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod –Uri $url –Headers $header -Body $body –Method PATCH
```

Comment: I guess step 2. may also be scripted, that is the `-RequiredResourceAccess` arg?

Comment: @reim yes, but it just adds the permission without `Grant admin consent`.

Comment: For programmatic manifest control one can use the Azure CLI tools now, see `az ad app update`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `az ad app update --set` with Azure CLI to modify App Registration manifest properties

Here an example (I'm using Powershell script format):
(These commands are to disable oauth2Permissions properties but it can apply to most of the properties in the manifest)
You have to set to disable the "oauth2Permissions" first to modify any properties inside.

```
az ad app update --id $app_registration_id --set oauth2Permissions[0].isEnabled=false
```

Then you can modify it (in my case, I just want to clear all properties):

```
az ad app update --id $app_registration_id --set oauth2Permissions=[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this with Update-AzADApplication:

```
$AppReg = Get-AzADApplication -Filter "AppId eq '$($AzAppReg.AppId)'"
$WebData = $AppReg.Web | ConvertFrom-Json
$WebData.implicitGrantSettings.enableIdTokenIssuance = $true
$JsonOutput = $WebData | ConvertTo-Json
$AppReg | Update-AzADApplication -Web $JsonOutput
```

Comment: Very unconventional, but this actually works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me:

```
az ad app update --id <appid> --set oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow=false
```

Strange thing is that it complains that the property is not found, but yet it did work...

Answer (score 0):

With MS Graph :

Access tokens (used for implicit flows) --> (Get-MgApplication -ApplicationId Your_ObjectID).Web.ImplicitGrantSettings.EnableAccessTokenIssuance

ID tokens (used for implicit and hybrid flows) --> (Get-MgApplication -ApplicationId Your_ObjectID).Web.ImplicitGrantSettings.EnableIdTokenIssuance

Answer (score -2):

You can with AzureAD Powershell module (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAD):

```
Connect-AzureAD
Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId 82384e2a-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-11488797ce1d -Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow $true
```

You'll need the objectId of your app registration.

Comment: This sets up oauth2AllowImplicitFlow property, not oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow.