# AzureAD - oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow for app-registrations

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

As I was attempting to remove the additional configuration for on an app-registration created by PowerShell.. I came around a strange behaviour;

The this command *az ad app update --id  $app.appid --set oauth2AllowId**Token**ImplicitFlow='false'*
results in an exception namely "*az : Property 'oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow' not found on root. Send it as an additional property*". It however does **apply** the value.

Is there no documented way to automated this setting - as it can be send via the portal and via the API (Shoot and forget as per [How to setup oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow in azure AD application from console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56757068/how-to-setup-oauth2allowidtokenimplicitflow-in-azure-ad-application-from-console) )

And i was expecting it to be part of the Permission-grants ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft split the oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow out of oauth2AllowImplicitFlow.
To reliably set it from within Az-context is; use the API instead:

`az rest --method PATCH --uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<<Object_Id>' --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' --body '{\"web\":{\"implicitGrantSettings\":{\"enableIdTokenIssuance\":false}}}'`

(reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/10579)

Answer (score 1):

The command you have shared will not work as `oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow` was not the correct syntax of `az ad app update` as per [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_app_update).

The correct syntax will be

```
 az ad app update --id $app.appid --oauth2-allow-implicit-flow false
```

Comment: Thank you Hari,

Your suggest would indeed set the "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow" but not the "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow". 
New-AzADApplication automatically set the "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow" property and if you dont set it when removing oauth you a warning in the portal;
"NOTE: You have [...] remove these settings or register the appropriate redirect URI."

I am indeed looking to set a the property that is not in the API without using the previous referenced example on the graph-api as that would require a new authentication-scope in my script.

with kind regards,
Sebastian

Comment: And unfortunately 'az ad app update --id $app.appid --set oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow='false'' does the trick. Although the error, and non-documentation would make you wish it didn't.

Comment: Hi @Sebastian, For  your scenario please try `Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId "{id}" -oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow $false`

Comment: Greetings Hari, 
As i didnt have it installed i took a quick peek at the documentation; The flag 'oauth2AllowIdTokenImpliciteFlow' is not mentioned however i found an alternative way that does work -

az rest --method PATCH --uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<<Object_Id>' --headers 'Content-Type=application/json' --body '{\"web\":{\"implicitGrantSettings\":{\"enableIdTokenIssuance\":false}}}'
(reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/10579)

Thank for your help!

with kind regards,
Sebastian